# How to kill all the multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a python function which calls another function in a multiprocessing.How can I kill all the multiprocessing using python?

This is the outer function which is also a multiprocess

```
p = Process(target=api.queue_processor, args=(process_queue_in, process_queue_out, process_lock,
                                          command_queue_in, command_queue_out, api.OBJECTIVE_0_5NA, quit_event,
                                          log_file))
p.start()
```

This is the function which is getting called

```
def queue_processor(process_queue_in, process_queue_out, process_lock,command_queue_in, command_queue_out, objective_type_NA, quit_event,log_file=None):
  
                    slide, roi_coordinates = process_obj[0]
                    logger.info("Received for imaging {} with ROI {} and type {}".format(slide.tile_dir,
                                                                                         roi_coordinates,
                                                                                         slide.slide_type))

                    p = Process(target=iad.image_slide,
                                args=(slide.tile_dir, slide.slide_type, roi_coordinates, exception_queue,
                                      objective_type_NA, logger, clog_path))
                    p.start() #process to kill
```

I want to kill the second multiprocess.(commented)

Comment: Can you please give us sample code how you are using processes? The answer may depend on what module you are using. For e.g. with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor, cancel() can be called on returned Future instances, however that does not guarantee immediate termination. Generally sudden termination is not recommended because that may corrupt resources or leave system in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

We can kill or terminate a process immediately by using the terminate() method. We will use this method to terminate the child process, which has been created with the help of function, immediately before completing its execution.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
def Child_process():
   print ('Starting function')
   time.sleep(5)
   print ('Finished function')
P = multiprocessing.Process(target = Child_process)
P.start()
print("My Process has terminated, terminating main thread")
print("Terminating Child Process")
P.terminate()
print("Child Process successfully terminated")
```

Comment: basically there are two multiprocess. The outer function which is exposed is also a multiprocess and inner function which is getting called by the outer one is also a multiprocess. I want to kill the inner one